# Printing select lines after searching and finding what I want

Tags: python

So I am searching through a .txt file which holds our router configs and I am specifically searching for the keyword "interface" and then wanting to print out the following 3 lines. This is my code but it doesn't print anything at all when I try to print it. Any feed back would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
For file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if file[-4:] == '.txt'
        file = open(file)
        for row in file:
            if re.search("interface", row):
                lines = [file.readline() for i in range(2)]
```

The .txt file would go something like this:

```
interface ethernet0/0/0
description This is a test file
ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface ethernet0/0/1
description this is another test file
ip address 192.168.0.2 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Didn't you consume already the lines in the `for` loop so to speak?

Comment: Please include a sample `.txt` file so we can run tests ourselves...

Comment: Just added a sample part of the .txt file, as for it being consumed in the for loop I'm not sure what you mean by that I don't think it is being used up in the for loop, but there is the more than likely possibility of me being wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work. By "*...wanting to print out the following 3 lines*", I'm making the assumption you mean lines `i`, `i+1` and `i+2` if 'interface' is found on line `i`.

```
def get_lines_after_interface():
    with open('scratch.txt') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        return [lines[i:i+3] for i, line in enumerate(lines) if 'interface' in line]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    matches = get_lines_after_interface()
    print('\n---\n'.join('\n'.join(line for line in match) for match in matches))
```

**Example text input**

```
Here is a text file
containing the
word interface on line 3
this is line 4
line 5, also containing interface
line 6
line 7
and finally line 8 which shouldn't be seen
```

**Output**

```
word interface on line 3
this is line 4
line 5, also containing interface
---
line 5, also containing interface
line 6
line 7
```

---

With the text file you provide, I get this output:

```
interface ethernet0/0/0
description This is a test file
ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
---
interface ethernet0/0/1
description this is another test file
ip address 192.168.0.2 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Thank you! This seemed to do the trick. Your help is greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your input file is something like this:

```
interface ethernet0/0/0
description This is a test file
ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
Do not show
Do not show this too
interface ethernet0/0/1
description this is another test file
ip address 192.168.0.2 255.255.255.0
Do not show this
interface ethernet0/0/1
description this is another test file
ip address 192.168.0.2 255.255.255.0
```

You can loop through the file and so something like this:

```
data = list(k.rstrip() for k in open("f_input.txt", 'r'))
# Here i added ["\n"] as seperator between lists, you can add whatever you want
# for example you can add a ["!"] or ["----"] etc..
a = [data[k:k+3] + ["\n"] for k in range(len(data)) if data[k].split(" ")[0] == 'interface']

for k in a:
    for j in k:
        print(j)
```

Output:

```
interface ethernet0/0/0
description This is a test file
ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0


interface ethernet0/0/1
description this is another test file
ip address 192.168.0.2 255.255.255.0


interface ethernet0/0/1
description this is another test file
ip address 192.168.0.2 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: the linebrakes might also be `\r\n` or `\r` depending on one's system. Not to worry with all that, you can do `.rstrip()` instead (not specify the newline character)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Thanks for pointing it out. You're right. I edidted my answer. Thanks again.